# Rails 3: Nested Resources 3 Levels Deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read [this article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) by James Buck, but it's a bit out of date.

Here's what I know is considered bad practice:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :users
  resources :roles
  resources :people do
    resources :notes
  end
end
```

Is this what I should be doing?

```
resources :companies do
  resources :users, :roles, :people
end

resources :people do
  resources :notes
end
```

And can someone please explain to me why or why not?

Comment: yes, that's the essence of it.

Answer (score 0):

Both will generate the exact routes for :companies , :users , :roles and for :people .

But :notes route will differ .

In first case for the :notes route will generate something like :

```
/companies/:company_id/people/:person_id/notes(.:format) 
/companies/:company_id/people/:person_id/notes/new(.:format)
```

and in second case routes will not relate with companies , and looks like :

```
/people/:person_id/notes(.:format)
/people/:person_id/notes/new(.:format)
```

So I think its depend on your application and which routes you want to prefer .

Hope this will help .

Comment: I understand that the routes will be different, but I'm more curious about what's considered best practice? I've read not to nest beyond two levels, so is my second example considered Best Practice? I'm new to Rails and want to start off on the right foot.